# The minified css and js files are not getting copied to final war file using minify-maven-plugin

Tags: javascript, css, minify

I am trying to minify all my css and js files. Then I want to have them in the final war file. I dont want to change the file names ie i want only content should be minified of each file and should go to the war file.

This is my **pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>                   
        <version>1.7.2</version>
        <executions>
                <execution>
                        <id>minify</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                                <goal>minify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                                <charset>utf-8</charset>
                                <jsEngine>CLOSURE</jsEngine>                           
                                <closureCompilationLevel>WHITESPACE_ONLY</closureCompilationLevel>
                                 <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
                         <skipMerge>true</skipMerge>
                            <verbose>true</verbose> 
                                <cssSourceDir>/ui/css</cssSourceDir>
                                <cssTargetDir>/ui/css</cssTargetDir>
                                <cssSourceIncludes>
                                        <cssSourceInclude>*.css</cssSourceInclude>
                                </cssSourceIncludes>

                                <jsSourceDir>/ui/js</jsSourceDir>
                                <jsTargetDir>/ui/js</jsTargetDir>
                                <jsSourceIncludes>
                                        <jsSourceInclude>*.js</jsSourceInclude>
                                </jsSourceIncludes>
                        </configuration>
                </execution>
        </executions>
</plugin>
```

Here the packaging of war file is happening first and then the minification happening.

This is output in command line after running pom file

```
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ ProductActivationServer ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [ProductActivationServer] in [C:\ProductActivationServerUI\pas\ProductActivationServer\target\pas]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\ProductActivationServerUI\pas\ProductActivationServer\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [13993 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\ProductActivationServerUI\pas\ProductActivationServer\target\pas.war
[INFO] WEB-INF\web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO]
[INFO] --- minify-maven-plugin:1.7.2:minify (minify) @ ProductActivationServer ---
[INFO] Starting CSS task:
[INFO] Skipping the merge step...
[INFO] Creating the minified file [C:\ProductActivationServerUI\pas\ProductActivationServer\target\pas\ui\css\BreadCrumb.css].
```

So in final war original content there but not minified.

Please help. I am using mvn , struts web app.

I am trying to minify all my css and js files. Then I want to have them in the final war file. I dont want to change the file names ie i want only content should be minified of each file and should go to the war file.

Answer (score 0):

When both the options `nosuffix` and `skipMerge` are set to `true`, the plugin execution phase needs to be set to `package`, otherwise the output files will be overridden by the source files during the packaging.
You also need to [exclude source files from WAR package](http://samaxes.github.io/minify-maven-plugin/examples/exclude.html).